# Turning your browser into proxy server

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, cross-browser, http-proxy

I have a logic written on my server mostly doing curl requests (e.g. accessing social networks). though, some of the sites, will be blocking my server(s) IPs soon.

I can of course, use VPN or deploy multiple servers per location, but it won't get accurate, and still some of the networks might get block the user account.

I am trying to find creative solution to run it from the user browser (it is ok to ask for his permission, as it is an action he is explicitly trying to execute) Though I am trying to avoid extra installations (e.g. downloadable plugins\extension or a desktop app)

Is there a way to turn the client browser into a server-proxy, to run those curl-calls from his machine instead of sending it from my own server? (e.g. using web-sockets, polling, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what sort of curl requests you are making. In theory, you could simulate these using an XMLHttpRequest. However, for security reasons these are generally not allowed to access resources hosted on a different site. (Imagine the sort of issues it could cause for instance if visiting any website could cause your browser to start making requests to Facebook to send messages on your behalf.) Basically it will depend on the [Cross-origin request policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) of the social networks that you are querying. If the requests being sent are intended to be publicly available without authentication then it is possible that your system will work, otherwise it will probably be blocked.